# How to make a port listener code in the server that hosts my website?

Tags: php, tcp, sockets

I have my website hosted in godaddy, and I want to test one of the Embedded Application's TCP data transfer using the IP and port number of my website, for this can I use any php script ([something like a port listener](https://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/PHP/56/))that can be run using the browser? which could print out the data received over tcp?

I'm not used with php, can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser. It's being run on the server. If you want to check a TCP port consider using `telnet`. Maybe try to be a bit more expressive with what you want to do.

Comment: hi , I mean to say, upload the php file to the server and access it though browser?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, most godaddy accounts are shared. It means you don't have access to either root or firewall. In this case you cannot do it there - either using PHP or in any other way.

If you do have root and made sure the firewall allows input connections to the port you want then you can use a tcp wrapper like `xinetd` to let any script you like to listen on certain port. Please note it is generally a bad idea because such wrappers may not handle simultaneous connections properly.

If you still want it, make sure the port you want to use is not occupied by another process (like 80 and 443 by webserver). The places where you able to direct the php script output to are e.g. file or database. Yuo cannot send the data directly to a browser because in chain sender-xinted-php there's no browser. You'll need e.g. another php script which will be run behind webserver to get data from either file or DB and send it to browser.

Comment: so can I write a php script in the server(where my site is hosted) to listen to a port, and may be print what is received or write to a file? . I will be sending data(client) to the ip and port form a GSM module. Now I'm sending it to port 80 but I have no way to see what is coming there on server.

Comment: "Print" usually means "send to output". There's no default output for service unless you specify it (e.g. file). If you want to see what is coming there on server - write a log then you'll be able to watch it in real time from shell e.g. `tail -f /path/to/log_file` (I assume you're on Linux)

Comment: can I do this with just accessing the ip and port (form the client , the gsm module) using only TCP protocol, or should I use an http post?

Comment: You need to study network stack, http impiies tcp but tcp is not necessary http. You can use whatsoever you want, even icmp or udp but transmitter and receiver should understand each other. If your server script does not understand http then there's not much sense to send post requests. Xinetd mainly works with tcp.